# Delete Facebook Posts Automatically from user profile

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I want to be able to run a script that auto deletes my Facebook posts/activity once it is run.

I have wrote the script so that at present it collates all of the posts that are present on a user profile, however Im unsure how to now delete the posts automatically, as this would be the final step for the script.

```
import requests
import pprint
import sys

# See http://www.unixtimestamp.com/ to generate Unix timestamps online
payload = {
            'until': 1566691200, # Unix timestamps
            'since': 1072915200, # Unix timestamps
            'limit': 1000, # number of posts
            'access_token': '', # your access token

        }

#Variables

id = 'id'
name = 'name'

base_api = 'https://graph.facebook.com'
posts_endpoint = base_api + '/me/posts/'

posts_response = requests.get(posts_endpoint, params=payload)

if posts_response.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
    print('Error: ' + posts_response.json()['error']['message'])
    sys.exit(0)

posts_dict = posts_response.json()['data']
pprint.pprint(posts_dict)

print("Total posts to delete: %d" % len(posts_dict))
for post in posts_dict:
    #print("Deleting [%s] %s" % (post['id'], post['name']))
    requests.delete(base_api + '/' + post['id'], params=payload)
    #print("Deleted [%s] %s\n" % (post['id'], post['name']))
```

As expected it prints a list of current posts on a %user page.

Comment: You can not delete posts on a user profile. Back when that was possible, it was only possible for posts created by the app itself, and now it isn’t possible at all any more, because the required permission `publish_actions` has been removed a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Your request.delete method is correct but

You can see the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#deleting

That says, it only needs the access token as parameter in the delete request.

```
curl -i -X DELETE \
    "https://graph.facebook.com/{your-page-post-id}?access_token={your-page-access-token}"
```

Or you can use POST method

```
curl -i -X POST \
    "https://graph.facebook.com/{comment-id}?method=delete&access_token={access-token}"
```

And keep your access token private

Comment: So forgive me for being a little absent minded at the minute, but the curl DEL function you suggested is to be placed at the end of my script?

Comment: No, just pass only the access token in the payload. payload={'access_token':' '}